# Pandas choose last row of second index with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have grouped by some data according to and ID and Month_ID and got double indexed dataframe. Now I want to choose the last row of each group, example:

```
ID      MONTH_ID    
0001    201901      
        201902      
        201903      

0002    201912
        202001
```

I want to choose

```
ID      MONTH_ID    
0001    201903      

0002    202001
```

However I couldn't come up with a way to choose according to the second index, since with mltiindexing iloc is not very helpful and the length of each index in MONTH_ID is different for each group.
I have also tried to use nth(-1) on the groupby object but that didn't help as well.

I came across multiple questions and answers and looked up the documentation but I didn't find a way to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried to use nth(-1) on the groupby object but that didn't help as well.

I think this should solve your problem, I don't know what went wrong in what you did. Maybe you didn't reset the index before applying the groupby.

Try this:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('ID').last()
```